# Sharepoint 2013 list edit form save conflict

Tags: save

I'm new in SP development.

Currently I have problem with my SP list. I have created *InfoPath* form where users can enter value for just one field, but if several users open form the same time just one value saving in the list, all another getting save conflict error, but then form allow them to enter data, but these data has not seen in list.

How can I do edit form reloading every 5 sec for example.
I have found one post but I could not realize it. [refer here](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/sharepoint-error-save-conflict-your-changes-conflict-with-those-made-concurrently-by-another-user/#comment-9058)